# Listening to Events

Tags: solidity, events

Can we still listen to an event if it has no indexed variables?

What I mean is, if we emit some event such as:

```
emit LogTrueOrFalse(bool TrueOrFalse);
```

Are we able to get the value of the boolean each time this event is emitted without using any indexed variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, arguments are still available. Marking one as `indexed` just makes it easier to filter the events for a certain value.